# Managing rank of records via apex in salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a requirement I'd like to get some input on.  I need to have an "account rank" field that will not include all accounts and I will need to be able to add to the pool, remove from the pool, and change rank.  My problem is that each time I remove a record from the pool or move it to a new position, all records after (which could be as many as 10,000) will need to be shifted up or down.  Salesforce has limits on individual updates of 200 at a time, or you can split it up into batches of up to a million.  My concern with batches is I won't be able to guarantee that people won't update more than 5 records in a short time, therefore reaching past the salesforce limits on total # of batches allowed.

Has anyone dealt with these issues and do you have any suggestions for a best approach?

Answer (score 0):

(I'd post this as a comment but I'm new and can't do that yet.  Sorry).

I can't think of a good way to model this in the way you describe without resorting to some pretty custom apex using @future or batch, or having your own integration that does this recalculation through the salesforce API.

What determines account rank?  Can you calculate it inside of a formula field?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one... Can you re-think about this to somehting more SFDC-like? What if you were to generate the ranks on a dinamic way? You could for example create a voting system, or some grading system and have SFDC calculate the ranking for you.

Let's say you have one or more fields where you give a grade then have a SOQL query like this:

[SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE *_* ORDER BY Vote1, Vote2, ]

Answer (score 0):

If you change your Data Model it should make this quite easy e.g.

1. Create a ranking object Ranking__c and associate this with the Account object.
2. For each rank type or number create
   a record with the details.
3. Associate the appropriate Account
   records with the corresponding
   Ranking__c record

When it's time to update an Accounts rank just change the Ranking__c records instead of the Account records. This should massively reduce the number of records you'd need to run over.